# matplotlib plot function; automatically set the x and y axis matched up

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an one dimensional numpy array can be any length. 
Meanwhile I want the array to be plot in a way such that x-axis can be any range.

For example;

```
y = np.random.randn(1000) # array to be plotted
max_x = 10000
min_x = 0
x = np.arange(min_x,max_x,max_x//y.shape[0])
plt.plot(x,y)
```

This will plot `y` such that `x` axis starts with 0 and ends with 10000.

However, if I have

```
y = np.random.randn(1134) # array to be plotted
max_x = 30000
min_x = 0
x = np.arange(min_x,max_x,max_x//y.shape[0])
plt.plot(x,y)
```

this doesn't work because `x` and `y` doesn't match.

Since my `max_x` and `y.shape[0]` can be any size.

Is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: Do you mean `x = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, len(y))`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest; yes! Thanks !